# What happens after you reach the 10gb limit in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I've read that Google Cloud SQL is recommended for small to medium sized applications. I was wondering if it's possible to spread my data across multiple instances in Google Cloud SQL. Say in instance 1 I have 10 tables, 1Gb each, and after a while table A needs more space, say 1.5Gb. Now there's not enough space for all this data in one single instance, how do you spread table A data across different instances? Is it possible to do so?

Thank you,
Rodrigo.

Comment: Why you downgraded the question????

Answer (score -1):

As per the [google storage documentation](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2736257):

*If you reach the free storage limit, everything in Google Drive, Gmail and Picasa will still be accessible, but you won't be able to create or add anything new over the free storage limit.*

Comment: The question is about Google Cloud SQL not Google Drive.

Comment: @SebastianKreft not sure why did it require a downvote, but same google policy applies to both Google drive and google cloud SQL.

Comment: Still this does not address the question. He is asking how to spread a table across different instances. Also the 10GB limit is per SQL instance and has nothing to do with free quota.

Comment: Indeed, your answer doesn't adress my issues.